# Viewpager loose fragment connection on low memory kill

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, fragment, low-memory

in my activity i use viewpager. I create two fragments and attach the to the view pager and time to time calling some methods from this fragments in my activity.. afer the app is killed on low memory and recreated fragments are there but no connection with the viewpager somehome.. i can not call MyFragment.mymethod().. it says MyFragment is null

```
 public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            if(position==0){
                if(homeFragment==null){
                    homeFragment=new HomeFragment();
                }
                return homeFragment;
            }else{
                if(mapFragment==null){
                    mapFragment=new Map();
                }
                return mapFragment;
            }
        }
```

.
.
.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id==R.id.action_search){
            return true;
        }else if(id==R.id.action_feedback){

        }else if(id==R.id.action_rate_me){

        }else if(id==R.id.action_show_favorites ){
            if(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()!=0){
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
            homeFragment.populateListWithFavorites();
            return true;

        }else if(id==R.id.action_history){
            if(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()!=0){
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
            homeFragment.populateListWithHistory();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Just  to make sure I understood - when you say the app is killed and then recreated, you mean that the app completely terminates and then on a fresh start of the app, there is no connection between the ViewPager and the fragments?

Comment: No, i mean when you open app and then return to home screen and do other stuff like using other apps and so on the app is killed on low memory by android, and than you open the task list on android and click on app again. It creates the activity again with its fragments... but the recreated fragments has no connection with the viewpager of the activity

Comment: ok.. so now what happens when you kill the app's main activity yourself by pressing the back button and then restart it later?

Comment: it is ok when i killed the app myself... everything works as expected

Comment: Do you have the ViewPager inside the onCreate() method alone? I think that the app is really not getting killed and only onStop() has been called. Hence when you restart the app, it calls onRestart() but not onCreate() and for some reason this instance is not persisting (I am not sure why) but can you let me know what happens when you also put ViewPager inside of onRestart()? Also, how do you say that Android has terminated the app - do the logs indicate onDestroy() was called? In that case, also override onDestroy() to include this.finish() to make certain it terminates.

Comment: I can say that Android has terminated it because:
   1) all the values cleand, variables resetted
   2) and that does not happen if i just go to homepage and comeback. it happens only when i opens lots of other apps and create some low memory situation and than go back to app

OnDestroy() is not called for sure... I did put there some logging and it didnt even fired...

I will try to put the viewpager in onRestart() too and let you know of the result

Comment: nope... didn't work :(

Comment: I am out of ideas on this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution....

it is really like a said that my fragment variables in the main activity is cleared so i have no connection to the fragments anymore.. what i did is inside the onAttach() i linked my fragment to the mainActivity variables again

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = activity;
        ((RestaurantActivityViewPager)mActivity).menuFragment=this;
    }
    public static MenuFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        MenuFragment fragment = new MenuFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get tabFragment by this code

```
Fragment fragment = mPagerAdapter.getItem(position);
```

It caused that bug when low memory.
Try with this one

```
fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.rewards_viewpager + ":"+position);
```