# system recreate fragment when app back from low memory

Tags: android, memory, android-viewpager, fragment

My app has one activity which has a ViewPager. There are several fragments in the ViewPager.

There is a bug. When I click "home" to hide my app, and start a lot of other apps, which are memory killer, than I click icon to call back my app, the fragments are out of order.

I had debug many days and finally find that, when app come back from low memory, it restart the activity from beginning, I mean it start from activity's static initial code to onCreate(). But, system also automatically create the fragments for me, which is not by my code, and lack of initialization.

I know what system want to do. It want to help app restore the state before suffer low memory. When low memory, system killed my fragments.

I have two questions:

(1) When system recreate fragment for me, how can I receive it? I mean, I have a lot of data structure which point the old fragment, how can I change this pointers to the new fragments? I find one way, when the automatic recreated fragment arrive onAttach(), replace the old pointer value in activity with the address of this fragment. Just like this:[Viewpager loose fragment connection on low memory kill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915595/viewpager-loose-fragment-connection-on-low-memory-kill). If this is the official way and the best way?

(2) In some case I really needn't restore the state before low memory. I want restart app to have a clear app. So, if there is an option to prevent system recreate fragment or other state for me?

Answer (score 1):

(1) You need to save out all the data you want to preserve in the override `onSaveInstanceState`. Then this state is given back to you in the `onCreate` method.

(2) If your application has only one activity, you can call `finish` from the `onStop` override. Then your app will be restarted every time it is sent to the background.